# findByIdAndRemove cannot remove more than one doc at same time in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to remove more than one doc at same time, the idea is sent to the findByIdAndRemove method a few `_ids`, the problem looks like something in the casting, but I have not idea how to solved it.

I was googling a bit but at the moment I did not find anything how can help me to understand what I do wrong. I am getting this error:

```
    (node:95729) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
      _id: {
        '$in': [
          '5f118f0c7bec9a497dfafbf0',
          '5f118fd93d847749e3ecffe3',
          '5f11902ff143154a16d8c940',
          '5f119061a407ef4a26a5b3bc'
        ]
      },
      user: { '$eq': '5efeaf2f3ded3b581c4ba695' }
    }" at path "_id" for model "Notification"
        at new CastError (/Users/papixulo/server/massages_backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
```

This is the code:

```
    const ids = req.body.ids;
    var object_ids_array: string[] = [];
    
    ids.forEach(id => {
        return object_ids_array.push((id));
    });
    
    
    console.log('******ids_array',  object_ids_array);
    
    // var id = new ObjectId(request.params.Id);
    // Booking.findOne({packages: {$in: packages_ids}}).select('_id _package _date').exec()
    
    await Notification.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: {$in: object_ids_array}, 'user': {$eq: req.user._id}}, (err: any, docs: any) => {
        console.log('docs', docs);
        console.log('err', err);
    
    if ( err || !docs) {
            validations.push({code: 150, message: 'error_removing_notification'});
        }
    if( validations.length > 0 ) {
        return res.status(400).json( {
            code: 400,
            error: validations
        });    
    }

    return res.status(200).json({
        code: 200,
        success: true
    });
});
```

And just in case this is the model:

```
const notificationSchema = new Schema ( {
    
    title: {
        type: String
    },

    notification_type: {
        type: String
    },

    text: {
        type: String
    },

    isRead: {
        type: Boolean
    },

    date: {
        type: Number // When the notification will be triggered?
    },

    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a user must exist']
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved it with I solved it with deleteMany()
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany